# Hibernate Annoation only bundle

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I am looking for a Maven artifact that only contains the hibernate annotation without the hibernate-core. I try to get small model bundle.

It seems up to hibernate 3 there was:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-annotations

The common annotations seems not to contain @Type and many more
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations

What is the best practice for this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I don't know if it is **allowed** by `hibernate` license

You can **extract** `org.hibernate.annotations` package to your final jar.
You will have compile-time dependency on `hibernate-core`, but only `org.hibernate.annotations` package will be included in your final jar.

Using `maven-dependency-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>extract-hibernate-annotations</id>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>unpack</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
              <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
              <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
              <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
            </artifactItem>
          </artifactItems>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
          <includes>org/hibernate/annotations/**</includes>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

And you have to add `hibernate-core` as your provided dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Testing:

`Main.java`:

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.SQLDelete;

@SQLDelete(sql = "delete from whatever where id = ?")
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SQLDelete annotation = Main.class.getAnnotation(SQLDelete.class);
    System.out.println("Sql delete = " + annotation);
    System.out.println("Sql = " + annotation.sql());
    try {
      Class.forName("org.hibernate.Session");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("org.hibernate.Session is not present");
    }
  }
}
```

`pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.caco3</groupId>
  <artifactId>so</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>extract-hibernate-annotations</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                  <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
              <includes>org/hibernate/annotations/**</includes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>
                Main
              </mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Build:

```
$ mvn package
$ java -jar target/so-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Output:

```
Sql delete = @org.hibernate.annotations.SQLDelete(callable=false, check=NONE, sql=delete from whatever where id = ?)
Sql = delete from whatever where id = ?
org.hibernate.Session is not present
```

Jar contents:

```
├── Main.class
├── META-INF
│   ├── MANIFEST.MF
│   └── maven
│       └── com.caco3
│           └── so
│               ├── pom.properties
│               └── pom.xml
└── org
    └── hibernate
        └── annotations
            ├── AccessType.class
            ├── Any.class
            ├── AnyMetaDef.class
            ├── AnyMetaDefs.class
            ├── AttributeAccessor.class
            ├── BatchSize.class
            ├── Cache.class
            ├── CacheConcurrencyStrategy$1.class
            ├── CacheConcurrencyStrategy.class
            ├── CacheModeType$1.class
            ├── CacheModeType.class
            ├── Cascade.class
            ├── CascadeType.class
            ├── Check.class
            ├── CollectionId.class
            ├── CollectionType.class
            ├── ColumnDefault.class
            ├── Columns.class
            ├── ColumnTransformer.class
            ├── ColumnTransformers.class
            ├── CreationTimestamp.class
            ├── DiscriminatorFormula.class
            ├── DiscriminatorOptions.class
            ├── DynamicInsert.class
            ├── DynamicUpdate.class
            ├── Entity.class
            ├── Fetch.class
            ├── FetchMode.class
            ├── FetchProfile$FetchOverride.class
            ├── FetchProfile.class
            ├── FetchProfiles.class
            ├── Filter.class
            ├── FilterDef.class
            ├── FilterDefs.class
            ├── FilterJoinTable.class
            ├── FilterJoinTables.class
            ├── Filters.class
            ├── FlushModeType.class
            ├── ForeignKey.class
            ├── Formula.class
            ├── Generated.class
            ├── GenerationTime.class
            ├── GeneratorType.class
            ├── GenericGenerator.class
            ├── GenericGenerators.class
            ├── Immutable.class
            ├── Index.class
            ├── IndexColumn.class
            ├── JoinColumnOrFormula.class
            ├── JoinColumnsOrFormulas.class
            ├── JoinFormula.class
            ├── LazyCollection.class
            ├── LazyCollectionOption.class
            ├── LazyGroup.class
            ├── LazyToOne.class
            ├── LazyToOneOption.class
            ├── ListIndexBase.class
            ├── Loader.class
            ├── ManyToAny.class
            ├── MapKeyType.class
            ├── MetaValue.class
            ├── NamedNativeQueries.class
            ├── NamedNativeQuery.class
            ├── NamedQueries.class
            ├── NamedQuery.class
            ├── Nationalized.class
            ├── NaturalIdCache.class
            ├── NaturalId.class
            ├── NotFoundAction.class
            ├── NotFound.class
            ├── OnDeleteAction.class
            ├── OnDelete.class
            ├── OptimisticLock.class
            ├── OptimisticLocking.class
            ├── OptimisticLockType.class
            ├── OrderBy.class
            ├── ParamDef.class
            ├── Parameter.class
            ├── Parent.class
            ├── Persister.class
            ├── Polymorphism.class
            ├── PolymorphismType.class
            ├── Proxy.class
            ├── QueryHints.class
            ├── ResultCheckStyle.class
            ├── RowId.class
            ├── SelectBeforeUpdate.class
            ├── Sort.class
            ├── SortComparator.class
            ├── SortNatural.class
            ├── SortType.class
            ├── Source.class
            ├── SourceType.class
            ├── SQLDeleteAll.class
            ├── SQLDelete.class
            ├── SqlFragmentAlias.class
            ├── SQLInsert.class
            ├── SQLUpdate.class
            ├── Subselect.class
            ├── Synchronize.class
            ├── Table.class
            ├── Tables.class
            ├── Target.class
            ├── Tuplizer.class
            ├── Tuplizers.class
            ├── Type.class
            ├── TypeDef.class
            ├── TypeDefs.class
            ├── UpdateTimestamp.class
            ├── ValueGenerationType.class
            ├── Where.class
            └── WhereJoinTable.class
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know hibernate jar that will contain only clean annotations including @Type and nothing else hibernate related.

I am try to guess, you want to get a jar that will contains code that uses @Type annotation in import, but does not depend on hibernate-core.

Use **provided** maven scope for this case.

Google says

> Maven dependency scope – provided. Maven dependency scope provided is
>   used during build and test the project. They are also required to run,
>   but should not exported, because the dependency will be provided by
>   the runtime, for instance, by servlet container or application server.

What means '*requied to run*' and '*will be provided*' here is that classpath have to load

```
org.hibernate.annotations.Type
```

From anywhere, most probably from existed hibernate-core jar, but in fact it is not necessary to be exactly hibernate-core. Java class coordinates is class_name + package + classloader. There is some considerations on special packages names like **java.lang**, but not for **org.hibernate.*** if you will create your own jar, that will contain this same package + annotation with same name, effect will be the same.

In other words you can create your own @Type annotation itself in your own jar if you strictly don't want it from hibernate-core.

Hope this will help.